# node-mysql pool and socket.io

Tags: mysql, node.js, socket.io

I'm currently using a single mysql connection for all the users on my app.
I would like to start using a pool (it should be more optimized, right?) but I have a "structural" problem: the *createPool* method only works with callback and I can't understand how to pass the connection to the socket.io event.

I mean, in the server.js file there is a point where the connection is build

```
pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
    //I'm supposed to use the connection here
}
```

and then there is a point where the socket events are "catched"

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('userLogin', function(id_user){
        //I need the connection here to run a query with 'id_user'!
    });
});
```

In the second point I need the connection and then I can run

```
connection.query('SELECT bla bla bla...', function(err, data){
    connection.end();
});
```

I think this is the only way to have a different connection for every user connected to the app but I really can't understand how to "pass" the connection to the socket.io "space".

Answer (score 2):

Ask the pool for a connection when you need it:

```
var pool = mysql.createPool(...);

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {

  socket.on('userLogin', function(id_user) {
    pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
      // assuming err was null here...
      connection.query(..., function(err, data) {
        // return the connection to the pool as soon as possible
        connection.end();

        // process data
        ...
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Because of the pooling, `pool.getConnection()` is a pretty cheap call so there's not big impact when you call it on-demand.

Comment: ok but let's suppose that I need to run a setInterval inside my 'userLogin' event (or another one) to continuously check something about my user.
Do I need to call "getConnection" and "end" every tick? I mean...do I have to create and destroy a connection every 5 seconds?!

Comment: You're not destroying a connection every 5 seconds, you're getting one from the pool (and giving it back once you're done with it). The alternative would be to create a connection for every client, which isn't very scalable.

Comment: I already tested this solution few days ago but I always got a lot of "read ETIMEDOUT" errors. I'll try again...

Comment: I guess it depends on what exactly is causing those timeouts.

Comment: The situation was pretty similar. Inside the "userLogin" event I have a setInterval loop where the getConnection is called, the connection.end is called and then the data are processed.
There are 6 socket.io events with 6 setInterval loop starting when requested.
It works until there are users online. If there is a time slot without any user, then the "read ETIMEDOUT" error show up!

Comment: You should use `clearInterval` to remove those intervals when a socket is disconnected, otherwise you end up with events being emitted to sockets that have been disconnected. I don't think it's related to MySQL. Perhaps it's better to move those intervals to the client side?

Comment: Uhm...that's interesting. I removed the interval only when the user explicitly stopped the event.
I'll try to add the clearInterval to the "disconnect" evento of socket.io.
I thought was a mysql error because it was generated in the Pool.getConnection function!

Comment: It's rather hard to debug from here, so I'm not at all claiming to be right ;)

Comment: As I imagined, when I switched to the pool the "read ETIMEDOUT" error come back in the `pool.getConnection()` function!
I opened a [new post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16341905/node-mysql-pool-vs-single-connection) because I really can't understand where the error come from and so I think I need to ping in some way the connection (or the pool) before to use it.

Comment: Okay, did some testing, and `node-mysql` seems to be a pretty bad performer. No matter how I use it (pools, global connection, connection per client, connection per request), I can't get it to work properly if I have about 10 clients that request some data each second.

Comment: oh great :(
any better alternative to node-mysql?

Comment: Try [nodejs-mysql-native](https://github.com/sidorares/nodejs-mysql-native) or [node-mysql-libmysqlclient](https://github.com/Sannis/node-mysql-libmysqlclient). I don't have any experience with any of those, though (don't use MySQL too much).